# embedded-redis providing own executables

Tags: java, redis

I need to use the latest version of Redis, using the library https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis. I can provide my own executable but is there a place where I can download executables for different architectures. I have a mac when I run make after downloading Redis it builds a mac version only and not the unix version.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official redis download page](https://redis.io/download/) you can download executables for macOS x64, macOS arm64, Linux x64 and Linux arm64.

For other architectures, there are no *official* builds, but you can still find some inofficial builds. They are usually not up-to-date with the latest redis release though. E.g. [github.com/signalapp/embedded-redis](https://github.com/signalapp/embedded-redis/tree/2aee2439c3314dba5d03a09dda1897d891f774b3/src/main/resources) contains a redis build for Linux x86. And [github.com/tporadowski/redis](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis) is a Windows port of redis.

---

By the way, [github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis](https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis) has not been updated since 2020. But there are more up-to-date forks of this library. Especially [github.com/codemonstur/embedded-redis](https://github.com/codemonstur/embedded-redis) contains relatively new redis binaries for all mentioned architectures.